# How can I install Oracle 11g on OSX 10.11.1?

Tags: database

I want to install Oracle 11g on my mac machine and I don't know how to do it. I want to develop a web application with jee and I want to use an Oracle database.
Is it possible to run a native development environment on OSX ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way is to install VirtualBox and use one of the images Oracle supplies for developers:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html